# After rollback, unable to deploy Google App Engine module

Tags: android, google-app-engine

After deploying two times simultaneously from Android Studio by mistake, I had a "409 Conflict Another transaction by user XYZ is already in progress for app". I undid the transaction using appcfg rollback, as suggested:

```
Beginning interaction for module default...
0% Rolling back the update.
Success.
Cleaning up temporary files for module default...
```

The problem is that now any attempt to deploy the module does not pass 99%. The log is as follows:

```
95% Will check again in 1 seconds.
98% Will check again in 2 seconds.
99% Will check again in 4 seconds.
99% Will check again in 8 seconds.
99% Will check again in 16 seconds.
99% Will check again in 32 seconds.
99% Will check again in 60 seconds.
99% Will check again in 60 seconds.
99% Will check again in 60 seconds.
...
```

Thank you!

Comment: There seems to have been a glitch yesterday, we're having a training on GAE and multiple students suffered from this. It worked fine a couple of hours later.

Answer (score 0):

This has been happening a lot lately, it's mostly due to glitches on Google's side. 
The issue should resolve itself within the next few hours.

You an check [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9449) for more info.